# Extracting data from excel sheet into csv (or) Json using Javascript

Tags: javascript, charts, d3.js, export-to-csv

I need to extract the data from an excel sheet into csv or json format and then display the content in the form of charts(bar, pie and line) using javascript. I have been working on it since 2 days and not able to find any good source. Any help regarding this would be appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: This is covered in a lot of tutorials such as [Christophe Viau](http://christopheviau.com/d3_tutorial/) and I assume that you know how to get a spreadheet to csv.  The other issue you could have is cross site scripting, in which case you'll need to use a local web server.

Answer (score 1):

You can also pull data from a google spreadsheet as CSV data like this:

```
var spreadsheet = "https://docs.google.com/spreadsheet/pub?key=youruniquekeyhere&single=true&gid=2&output=csv"

d3.csv(spreadsheet, function (error, data) {
  // use your data here
});
```

Notice the output=csv at the end of that URL.

gid=0 is worksheet 1, gid=1 is worksheet 2 and so on. You must publish your worksheet to the web first to make it available.

In addition to Christophe Viau's tutorials, here are more resources:

https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Gallery#basic-charts

http://www.d3noob.org